# Refresh page after window.history.go(-1);

Tags: php, redirect, authentication, refresh

On my website I've got a sidebar with a sort of "log in status" bar and when you are logged in it says "Log out" with a link to login.php?logout. This is the code on login.php:

```
if (isset($_GET["logout"])) {

    $this->doLogout();
    ?>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        window.history.go(-1);
    </script>
    <?php;                                      
}
```

when you click the logout link you are logged out and redirected to the previous page but then, in the login status bar, it still says "you are logged in". But when you refresh the page it says "you are not logged in". How can I let the page where the logout link is on refresh once autmatically after you are redirected to it?

Comment: You could do a 'real' redirect instead of using the browser history.

Comment: but then you would always be redirected to the same page instead of the page where you clicked "log out" and thats not what I want

Comment: how do I do this? Sorry but I'm a bit of a php noob

Comment: You can dynamically generate the URL to which you want to redirect the user. (e.g. by using his last visited URL)

Comment: thanks! I used `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']` is there also a way to get the second last url someone visited?